# Vertical alignment for a fluid div displaying images of different heights

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Alright.. here's the deal. I've been modifying a WordPress theme I purchased a while ago and I've hit a wall.
Unfortunately, I'm not CSS literate. I can adjust stuff, but I doubt I will be able to solve this on my own. So, here's a cry for help :)

The website and the div's code are bellow: http://photography.hamsterwheelproject.com/category/photo-of-the-day/

```
element.style {
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
display: block;
}

#superbgimage img {
position: static !important;
height: auto !important;
width: 100% !important;
top: 0 !important;
margin: 0 auto;}
```

The idea is to have the images always displayed vertically centered. I'd like to keep the width to 100% and fill the screen horizontally, while maintaining the photos' aspect ratio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can give your container a fixed height, it's easy with CSS:

```
#superbgimg {
    line-height:800px; /* height of screen */
}

#superbgimg img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

If you can't set a fixed height in your CSS, you can set it dynamically with JQuery (or any other javascript solution) quite easily:

```
$(function(){
    $('#superbgimg').css('line-height',$('#superbgimg').height() + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Thanks AlienWebguy!

I've tried with the first solution, but nothing changed. Granted, I've only used Firebug and changed it on the fly.

After I'll make the changes in my CSS, I'll update the situation.

Cheers!
Razvan

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happened after operating the changes in style.css.

Here's how the code looks now:
#superbgimage {
 display: none;
line-height:800px;
}
#content {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 3;
}

#superbgimage img {
 position: static !important;
vertical-align:middle;
 height: auto !important;
 width: 100% !important;
 top: 0 !important;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

Comment: #superbgimage can't be display:none if you want it to have a line-height. Try removing that and adding 'visibility:hidden' so it takes up space in the DOM. If you are fading it in and out, you can animate the opacity easily $('#superbgimage').animate({opacity:0},500); will fade it out. opacity:1 will fade it in.

Comment: hmm.. with 'visibility:hidden' the photos don't appear anymore, while without it the vertical centering doesn't happen.

'display: none' is commented in both situations. I hope I'm not doing anything wrong.. I did double check it though.

Comment: Well why is display none? Is it being faded in anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question, but - yes - there is a fading when making the transition from one photo to another.

Comment: ah.. Yes, in 19 .js files, but not in CSS or PHP files.
BTW, thanks for having so much patience with me ;)

Comment: No problem. fadeIn and fadeOut work with display:none and display:block - if you want to fade the opacity only you'll need to overwrite those functions. Why on earth are there 19 JavaScript files??

Comment: Erratum - there are only 4 .js files in the theme folder. I previously searched through the whole wordpress directory :D

Comment: Ok then look for those fades and swap them with the animates like in my comment 8 prior to this.